# AC not cold anymore on brand new VW Polo

Tags: ac

I've brought a new VW Polo 2012 plate. It's only a few months since it was registered by the dealer. However all a sudden the AC has stopped working. When I press the button labelled AC the light comes on. It's more effective to open the window!!

How might I troubleshoot this? I hear that your AC has to be serviced if it's not cold. But my car is effectively brand new. Before I go to the dealer is there anything I can check myself?

I've checked the fuses and there aren't any blown ones. I checked them all since there's no info on what each fuse does. Not even in the manual/fuse box lid!!

Answer (score 4):

If you bought it from a dealer, it should be under warranty. Don't go messing with trying to fix/recharge the A/C yourself or paying somebody to do it. Make them fix it. It's their problem.

If you really want to check some stuff yourself first, you could look in the fuse box(es) and see if there's a fuse labeled "A/C relay" or similar, and make sure it has continuity. Also, open the hood and make sure the condenser fan turns on when you press the A/C button. But really, unless the problem is as simple as a fuse, you want to make the dealer fix it. That's part of what you paid for when you spent dealer prices on a car.